# String with HTML tags isn't being recognized inside foreach

Tags: javascript, json, html, knockout.js

I have a string as a property in a JSON object. This string contains tags in order to set up some styles to it. The problem I'm facing is the fact that regardless of the well-written HTML tags it hasn't got the expected result. Shall I change my way of programming this part?

**Javascript - Viewmodel:**

```
function viewModel() {

   var self = this;
   self.text = ko.observableArray();
   self.text = ko.computed(function() {
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               async: false,
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               global: false,
               url: "../../webresources/myappresource/getitemdescription/001/102001/",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        itemdata = data;
                    }
                });
                return itemdata;
            }, this);

            this.itemsList = ko.observableArray(itemdata);             
     };
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**HTML + Knockout:**

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsList"  name="myitems">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input id="selectItem" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
          <h5 data-bind="text:itemDescription"></h5>
      </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**JSON object structure:**

```
[
    {
      "dscitem": " <b>Colour</b>: Green, <br/> <b>Weight</b>: 50.00,<br/> <b>Description</b>: suchitemdescription and so on,<br/> ",
      "skuitem": 110
    }
]
```

The result that would be expected is the same text enhanced with html tags. As opposed to that I'm getting the list I want which is cool, but the description shown is the whole string without any style, indeed, with the text in the same way as it is in the object, pure cosmic text to the app-user. Any ideas of what's happening in here?

Comment: Have you tried html binding - <h5 data-bind="html:itemDescription"></h5>?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin That works incredibly perfect sir, thanks. I hadn't tried that property of knockout, but now I know how it's implemented.

Comment: Ok, I've added my solution as an answer, could you accept it please?

Comment: For sure, I already did it! Your answer rocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (besides syntax errors in code snippets) that you're using text binding instead of [html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html).

So just replace

```
<h5 data-bind="text:itemDescription"></h5>
```

with

```
<h5 data-bind="html:itemDescription"></h5>
```